# How to send custom header in Google endpoints response

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using google endpoints frameworks but there is one requirement for me to send custom header to requester in the response.

But, in google endpoints all responses are returned as an object of Message class therefore was not able to find anyway to set my headers in the response to the requester.

Please help me with any such approach in which i can add my headers to the response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this by googling: [How to Add Custom Response Headers to Google Cloud Endpoints](http://www.pygopar.com/how-to-add-custom-headers-to-google-cloud-endpoints/)

Comment: I also encountered this post but i want a inbuilt functionality of endpoints (If any) to set headers for my request. instead of some patching

Comment: I'm the dev working on this framework, and I've added this as a feature request.

Comment: Thanks @RoseDavidson

Comment: Somewhat late comment but if there a `built-in` solution for this? I would expect a decorator where you define the header keyword for the desired endpoint: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/decorators-reference @RoseDavidson